# Reference for definition of multiple-output Gaussian process

Tags: regression, references, gaussian-process, definition

Does anyone know any good reference that has a clear and precise definition of **multiple-output** Gaussian process? Something like the definition of the Gaussian process in the third page of this set of slides ([pdf](http://mlss2011.comp.nus.edu.sg/uploads/Site/lect1gp.pdf)) would be greatly appreciated.

I am particularly looking for the kind of reference, such as a conference paper or a journal publication, that can be used in a technical paper. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are several papers [listed here](http://gaussianprocess.com/publications/multiple_output.php), though in a skim I didn't find a nice definition; most define certain subsets of kernels and define it only for that. You can WLOG use a single-output GP and replicate your data points with a discrete indicator for which output dimension it refers to, though.

Comment: @Dougal, Thank you very much for your reply. I have the same feeling with you that most paper define certain subsets of kernels. I found one definition of multivariate Gaussian process in a paper mentioned in the self-answer, which I believe is the same as a multiple-output Gaussian process.

Comment: See also the cross-post at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31311/8067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the literature, it seems that numerous papers have used the concept of **multiple-output Gaussian process**, but only a few include a definition. People also refer to it as **multivariate Gaussian process**. In fact, searching for the keyword of multivariate Gaussian process yields better references. Particularly, there is a definition of the multivariate Gaussian process at the beginning of section 3 in the paper:

"Gaussian predictive process models for large spatial data sets." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 70.4 (2008): 825-848, by Banerjee, Sudipto, et al